# How to select earliest date according to current sg

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to come with a SQL (SQL Server) that gets the earliest date according to the current sg. Below is the sample table where current sg is 4-3 (current because the end date is 1900-01-01). I want to get the date where the sg actually started (which is 2015-01-01) per employee. I really need some help on this.

```
empno      position             sg           date_from         date_to
4508       ADMIN AIDE IV        4-3          2017-01-01        1900-01-01
4508       ADMIN AIDE IV        4-3          2016-01-01        2016-12-31
4508       ADMIN AIDE IV        4-3          2015-01-01        2015-12-31
4508       ADMIN AIDE IV        4-2          2014-01-01        2014-12-31
4508       ADMIN AIDE IV        4-2          2013-01-01        2013-12-31
1207       AIRCRAFT MECHANIC I  6-1          1988-01-01        1989-06-30
1207       AIRCRAFT MECHANIC II 8-7          2006-05-08        2015-12-31
1207       AIRCRAFT MECHANIC II 8-8          2016-01-01        1900-01-01
0889       DATA ENTRY OPERATOR  1-1          2000-12-12        2001-06-30
0889       ADMIN ASSISTANT VI   12-5         2017-03-10        1900-01-01
0889       ADMIN ASSISTANT VI   12-5         2016-01-01        2016-12-31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can do that both with an inner query

```
select  min(date_from)
from    yourTable
where   sg = (
            select  sg
            from    yourTable
            where   date_to = '1900-01-01'
        )
```

or with a join

```
select  min(t1.date_from)
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.sg = t2.sg
where   t2.date_to = '1900-01-01'
```

**Edit**

To get the minimum date for each position, the easiest way is tweaking the second query into this:

```
select  t1.position, min(t1.date_from)
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.sg = t2.sg and
        t1.position = t2.position
where   t2.date_to = '1900-01-01'
group by t1.position
```

**Edit 2**

Since the requirement is to get the minimum date for each value in the the `empno` column, what you need to do is this

```
select  t1.empno, min(t1.date_from)
from    yourTable t1
join    yourTable t2
on      t1.sg = t2.sg and
        t1.empno = t2.empno
where   t2.date_to = '1900-01-01'
group by t1.empno
```

You can see it at work [here](http://rextester.com/TMXU22937)

Comment: This only gets one record. What if I have several employees and I have to get the earliest date of their sgs?

Comment: How can I add the employee number in the query without having a duplicate? Each employee should only have 1 record in the result.

Comment: There is no employee number in the table you described... where is it? Maybe in another table? Pleaae update your question

Comment: Updated my question sir.

Answer (score 1):

If a sg can't have multiple positions you could use the next query

```
SELECT t.position, t.sg, MIN(date_from) AS date_from
FROM @t AS t
    INNER JOIN 
      (select sg from @t where date_to = '19000101') as cur
    ON t.sg = cur.sg
GROUP BY t.position, t.sg
```

Comment: This works on certain records. I just can't understand why other records still gets the older sgs.

Comment: 0889 ADMIN ASSISTANT VI        12-5 2014-01-01
0889 DATA ENTRY MACHINE OP 1-1 2000-12-12
1207 AIRCRAFT MECHANIC H 6-1 1979-04-01
1207 AIRCRAFT MECHANIC I         6-1 1980-07-01
1207 AIRCRAFT MECHANIC II 8-1 1989-01-01
1207 AIRCRAFT MECHANIC II 8-7 2006-05-08
1212 CLERK I                                 3-1 1975-04-01
1212 CLERK II                                 4-1 1989-07-01
1212 PERSONNEL AIDE                 4-1 1987-02-17
1212 ADMINISTRATIVE OFFICER 22-1  2016-01-0

Comment: this are the results of the query. i've added the sample employee number to see the duplicated record for each employee.

Comment: I see you provided the results of the query, but can you provide the source data for employeenum 1207. I believe for this one you also get older sgs. Based on the result I can't see why it's not working the way you want. I also don't see duplicate records in your result. For employee I see different position with a different sg.

Comment: I noticed that when i added the employee number in the query, this happens. Can I prevent it? But then I should still get the employee number.

Answer (score 1):

**THE SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM YourTableNameHere
ORDER BY Sg DESC, Date_From
```

More Details:

Use ORDER BY in combination with TOP 1. Below I used a temp table that you can run in a NEW QUERY window.

Try this out:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
 Position varchar(20),
 Sg varchar(3),
 Date_From datetime,
 Date_To datetime)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (Position, Sg, Date_From, Date_To) 

SELECT 
        'ADMIN AIDE IV', '4-3', '2017-01-01', '1900-01-01'
UNION
SELECT 
        'ADMIN AIDE IV', '4-3', '2016-01-01', '2016-12-31'
UNION
SELECT 
        'ADMIN AIDE IV', '4-3', '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'
UNION
SELECT 
        'ADMIN AIDE IV', '4-2', '2014-01-01', '2014-12-31'
UNION
SELECT 
        'ADMIN AIDE IV', '4-2', '2013-01-01', '2013-12-31'


SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM #TempTable
ORDER BY Sg DESC, Date_From
```

Comment: This will only return one row, I think OP wanted to have one row per `sg`

Comment: Ya, probably so... I gave him what he asked for. Probably should've clarified. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below query :

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE 
    (ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),position VARCHAR(20), sg VARCHAR(10),date_from DATE,date_to DATE)

    INSERT INTO @t 
    VALUES
    ('ADMIN AIDE IV','4-3','2017-01-01','1900-01-01'),
    ('ADMIN AIDE IV','4-3','2016-01-01','2016-12-31'),
    ('ADMIN AIDE IV','4-3','2015-01-01','2015-12-31'),
    ('ADMIN AIDE IV','4-2','2014-01-01','2014-12-31'),
    ('ADMIN AIDE IV','4-2','2013-01-01','2013-12-31')

    SELECT  
        MIN(t1.date_from) AS [Earliest Date]
    FROM    
        @t t1 INNER JOIN @t t2 ON t1.sg = t2.sg
    WHERE   
        t2.date_to ='1900-01-01'
```